# OrientDB - convert String to Link in queries

Tags: type-conversion, orientdb

I have a map where the KEYS (although of type string) are meant to be LINKS (e.g. "#1:1", "#1:2") and I want to somehow be able to convert those string keys to LINKS and directly use them in queries.

E.g.

```
select  *  from  CONVERT_TO_LINK( myMap.keys()[0] )
```

How can I do such a conversion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**JS Function:**
[image]

**Test Code:**

```
create class v1 extends v
create property v1.myMap embeddedmap

create vertex v set name="pippo"
create vertex v1 set myMap={"#9:8":"something"}
select expand(link) from (select toLink(myMap.keys()[0]) as link from v1)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, it works!   Is this the only way to do that? Do you think the added function would slow down performance when this method is used on big amounts of db data?  (Btw, I am not sure how to confirm your answer via the system - I don't see any appropriate button or something. I also voted positively, but the system doesn't show it, because of some "reputation" related reasons...)

Comment: @mtqs https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `select  *  from myMap.keys()[0].convert('LINK')` built-in method?